# Remove date, author and their empty space from beamer titlepage

Tags: beamer, spacing, graphics, titles, presentations

I'm creating a presentation with the `beamer` class in which I don't need neither the date nor the author's name on the title page, so I removed them with `\author{}` and `\date{}`.

Now I'm trying to add an image to the title page but LaTeX leaves much space between the title and the picture, which I suppose to be the lines that should contain the author's name and the date:

[image]

How can I remove those empty lines?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{My title}
\author{}
\date{}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics{title-image}}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should comment the author and date definition:  

    %\author{}  
    %\date{}

Comment: @Emílio Kavamura It prints the date that I don't need (and that's why I made it empty with `\date{}`) and increases the spage between the title and the image.

Comment: so uncomment the date command:

   \date{}


   \titlegraphic{\vspace{-20mm}\includegraphics[width = .4\textwidth]{title-image}}


   and add a negative \vspace{} inside the titlegraphic in order to shift the image...

Comment: As proposed by Emílio Kavamura, you should use a negative space inside the `\titlegraphics` did you try this ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments and the OP didn't answer follow-up questions.